# broken javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a javascript function **defined somewhere** in the middle of my html/php based page like this -

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function popitup2() 
{
    newwindow2=window.open('','name','height=265,width=350');
    var tmp = newwindow2.document;
tmp.write('<html><head><title>Coupon</title>');
tmp.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo get_bloginfo('wpurl'); ?>/wp-content/themes/street/coupon.css">');
tmp.write('<script src="/street/coupon.js"> </script>');
tmp.write('<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"</script>');
```

...
/*some other code which is working fine */

Now this web page appears broken when i open it. But if i remove the the following 2 lines from javascript the error goes and page appears fine.

```
tmp.write('<script src="/street/coupon.js"></script>');
tmp.write('<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>');
```

Can someone tell what is wrong with coding of these lines.

Comment: ayush can you check if you just remove the first line containing coupoun.js what happens....

Comment: @sushil:still broken.Only when both lines are removed the error goes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The browser is interpreting the `</script>` in the string as the end of the `<script>` tag.

Change it to

```
tmp.write('<' + 'script src="/street/coupon.js"></' + 'script>');
```

Answer (score 1):

In your last line you have

```
tmp.write('<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"</script>');
```

which is missing the closing right-angle bracket. It should read:

```
tmp.write('<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>');
```

Now, when you give the line again to show what you removed, it's rendered correctly, so I'm not sure if this is really the problem or you just made a typo the first time. Worth a try.